# Why does Eclipse only suggest "Rename in file"?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I write

> somethingSomething = 2;

where somethingSomething is undefined, Eclipse only suggests "Rename in file".

This only happens for *one particular file*, and that particular file has a .java extension just like all the other files where Eclipse is more than prepared to make somethingSomething a field or whatever. What can I possibly have done to cause this?

Comment: what's the rest of the file look like?

Comment: It's a completely valid and compilable Java file.

Comment: Is this file in a Java project in Eclipse? (in the same project with the working ones)

Comment: Yes, it is. Which makes it weird!

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to not worry about it.

- Eclipse is a huge and complex application and has numerous strange behaviours that could be called bugs ... if you wanted to be picky about it.
- Stuff like error correction and completion is *necessarily* heuristic.  There's no way that Eclipse can predict with 100% accuracy what you actually meant ... and hence offer the most appropriate correction.

Comment: It is not that I am worried, but it is a highly useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you get if you open a file outside of the workspace. Eclipse will highlight the syntax, but it won't really check for errors, do syntax completion, etc.

Comment: It it not outside of the workspace. Eclipse does syntax highlighting as well as completion.